# Нужны кавычки при названиях песен, написанных нерусскими буквами?

Tags: кавычки

Нужны кавычки при названиях песен, написанных нерусскими буквами?

> Это часть песни «Il tempo se ne va», исполненной Михаилом Боярским и Тото Кукуньо.

> Это часть песни Il tempo se ne va, исполненной Михаилом Боярским и Тото Кукуньо.

Comment: Нет, не нужны кавычки. Насколько я знаю